# Web service .NET Framework problem

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, http-1.1

We are connecting a webservice (java) from C# (VS.Net 2003) application. Web service running on HTTP 1.0 protocol. On the other hand VS.Net 2003 trying to reach with HTTP 1.1 protocol.
Therefore objects are coming null value.

For example we are getting string[5] object is correctly but array's items are null value.

We have to take HTTP protocol to 1.0. With 2005 and 2008 no problem.

How can we do this in VS 2003 framework 1.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you get an example of what is expected to be posted for the 1.0 web service call?  If so, take a look at that and make sure everything is being passed in the soap envelope correctly and any settings that are added to the header.  I just updated an application that can be used to make SOAP calls using a WebRequest and it failed every time you tried to call a 1.1 web service.  There were multiple problems.

1) NameSpace

```
  - 1.2 = "soap12" 
  - 1.1 = "soap" 

  *Plus, the URL is different for each namespace.
```

2) ContentType

```
  - 1.2 = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"
  - 1.1 = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
```

3) When calling 1.1 web services I had to set the SOAPAction in the header.  Without it, kept getting a 500 error from the server.

I found this out by viewing the automatically generated test page generated by the web service (which has samples of a SOAP 1.1 and 1.2 call).  I then compared it to what we were building as our SOAP envelope / putting in header.  Once what we were generating matched the example, all worked as expected.

Since I do not know how you are calling the Java web service, the above information may or may not be applicable, but at least you have some things to check.

If you could post more specific information about how you are making the call to the web service in VS2003 (aka: code example) it would help get a more definitive answer.